# Split pdfs by keywords from command line

Tags: command-line, pdf

How can I split a pdf into multiple pdfs by using keywords as indicators where to split the pdf? For naming the resultant pdfs I just want to use a file with lists the target file names.

Comment: For getting the page number of where to split, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34627638/3628654) post may be of interest.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some examples. Ideally, upload a couple of example PDF files somewhere and then tell us how you would like those files split. If you cannot give examples, then at least give us more details: how many pages are these PDFs? How would you use " keywords as indicators where to split the pdf"? Should everything until the first keyword be split into a second file? Should all pages with the keyword be combined? The more detail you can give us, the better your chances of getting a useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

keyword="MyKeyword"

pdftotext $1 - | awk -vRS=$'\f' -vNAME=$keyword 'index($0,NAME){printf "%d\n", NR;}' > $1_index


## Generate ranges
prev=
paste $1_index | while read line
do
    if [ ! -z "${prev}" ];then
        line1="${prev}"
        line2="$((${line} -1))"
        echo "${line1}-${line2}"
    fi
    prev="${line}"
done > $1_ranges

## Split pdf
paste $1_ranges Names.dat | while read line1 line2;
do
    echo "pdftk $1 cat $line1 output $line2.pdf"
    pdftk $1 cat $line1 output $line2.pdf
done

## Handle last page
lastPage=$(tail -n 1 $1_index)
lastName=$(tail -n 1 Names.dat)

echo "pdftk $1 cat $lastPage-end output $lastName.pdf"
pdftk $1 cat $lastPage-end output $lastName.pdf
```

It should work at least if the segments match the number of the file names.